# UITableView item gets highlighted, and then gets deselected - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UIView with 3 nested UIViews. Their total width is 300% of screen. (100% each).
I'm changing AutoLayout priorities to bring the required on the screen and others off screen with buttons click from NavBar.

|uiview1| |uiview2| |uiview3|

uiview3 has a UITableView. It populates, scrolls perfectly, but on tapping an item, the item gets highlighted for a second and then released. The function 'didSelectRowAt' is NOT being called.

I have tried disabling every other gesture registered on this VC. The click is detected too but doesn't persist and gets deselected instantly.

```
//globally in VC
@IBOutlet weak var salamsTable: UITableView!

//in viewDidLoad
self.salamsTable.delegate = self
self.salamsTable.dataSource = self

//delegate functions
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    print (indexPath.row)  // this never gets called
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return self.allSalam.count      //works perfectly
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    var cell = self.msgsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messages") as! MessageCell
    return cell // works perfectly
}
```

[image: salamsTable is the subject UITableView]

Visual Demo:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Please post the relevant code when asking a question. There couple be many reasons a problem occurs, but with no code to evaluate it's hard to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: My guess would be that is has to do with the auto layout changes. Is there some reason you don't want to use a UINavigationController or a UIPageViewController to organize and display these three view controllers?

Comment: Will you share your demo ? I will solve it and return you with an answer

Comment: Are you overwriting who your delegate is supposed to be? It looks like you have the delegate set in storyboard and then again in code. 
`self.salamsTable.delegate = self
self.salamsTable.dataSource = self`
I would recommend removing these two lines as they are superfluous.

Comment: @JitendraModi I have added a visual demo to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @SpenserArn I have tried that too. The point is that all other delegates are working properly like cellForRowAt works perfect and populates the cell. The selection gets released thats the only issue. See the visual demo in my question.

Comment: @AqibBangash I understood your question very well but from this much code how can I understand what real issue is? That's why I am asking you for demo.

Comment: @AqibBangash what you are saying though is your datasource methods are working. cellForRow, numberOfRows are all dataSource. But is the delegate getting set properly?

Comment: @SpenserArn As an alternate i used didHighlightRowAt and it is also working. That concludes that all the delegates are working properly, but i guess the touch is being cancelled by some other view/scrollview/gesture recogniser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a Solution but an Alternate. Things worked out in another way. As you can see in the Demo GIF attached in the question, the cells are being highlighted properly. So i add the delegate method didHighlightRowAt and it worked like a charm.